# Are Leave Labour voters still an actual thing?

Tags: united-kingdom, brexit, labour-party

Leave Labour voters have been brought up in political chatter since the Brexit vote. They continue to be if today's Guardian Politics Weekly podcast is anything to go by.

But are they an actual thing nowadays?

Are there any recent polls around that give a feel of how big a group they are? Are they still a thing to be reckoned with, or just an odd voice that can be ignored?

If they're still important, how big are they nowadays?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [most recent poll](https://www.survation.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/Survation-Daily-Mail-Poll-25-September-Data-Tables.xlsx) on the subject of a potential EU referendum was conducted by Survation on 25 September.

Of voters who intend to vote Labour at the next General Election, 15% of them say they would vote to Leave in a subsequent referendum, compared to 77% who would vote Remain, and 8% undecided.

This is down slightly from Survation's [last poll before the referendum](https://survation.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/IG-Tables-21st-June.pdf), in which those who voted Labour in 2015 said they would vote around 25% to Leave vs 65% to Remain.

Comment: Might you be aware of polls done by other institutes that corroborate those numbers? Asking because as the answer stands it's too easy to dismiss as numbers ordered by a right wing rag that is barely a notch above the Sun in terms of credibility on the one hand side, and some financial outfit that might be in it for a profit on the other.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy The main reason I went with the Survation poll is that it's by far the most recent. The most recent I'm aware of before that is from 7 September, and given how much has changed since then, I'm reluctant to read too much into figures that old.